# Google Maps PlacesService, PlaceResult is only returning one (1) photo for the photos property array

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Having an issue with the results from the Google Maps PlacesService. The resultant PlaceResult object is now only returning one photo in the photos property array. In the past this was not the case and up to 10 photos were returned. Is this a change?

Example code:

```
var request = {
    reference: place.reference
}
var callback = function(details, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert("Number of photos: " + details.photos.length);
    }
}
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);
```

[fiddle showing an example](http://jsfiddle.net/tg2T8/1/)

Comment: Which version of API do you use? Experimental or release?

Comment: Google Maps API Version: 3, Tried both v3.16 and 3.exp. Same results with either version. But worked with multiple photos being return just a few days ago with no user code change.

Comment: Also tried some stock google code with the same results: 1 photo only.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for a place that _used_ to have more than 1 photo and/or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Here is a link to a public running Google Maps Sample place photos example that exhibits my problem exactly: only one photo return in results: [place-photos](https://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2691/trunk/places/place-photos.html)

Comment: Anything in particular we should search for in [your example](https://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2691/trunk/places/place-photos.html) that would exhibit the problem (return a result with one photo where previously more had been returned)?

Comment: Update: I tried using the new 'place_id' property as described in the [Updated Place Details Doc](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults). Same Results... Only 1 photo in array. Interesting, Google must be currently working with Place Details right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a previous answer that has been deleted I said that it must  be a bug on the Google side.

I just found this issue :

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6825&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

If I am right, the Google Maps PlacesService is the Javascript version of the Google Places API, so the backend code might be the same : that could explain why we have the same results (same bug(?)).

Hope this helps.